# I still get a truecolor image after using paint to crop a grayscale image (it is converted from truecolor)

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, crop, pixel

I have a truecolor image and I converted it to a grayscale image in matlab, I then save it as a new image.
This is the graylevel of the first few pixels from the new image.

[image]

I load this image to matlab, and then I take the first 15 row and 5 columns of the pixels, I can get the same graylevel value(which is no surpirse).

[image]

#### However

If I use Paint (the software comes with windows) to crop the first 15 rows and 5 columns of pixels from the converted grayscale image, and then save the cropped section as a new image.

The cropped image I get will still be a truecolor image.

If I convert the cropped image to grayscale, the graylevel values are different from previous two.

[image]

#### Anyone knows what is happening here? Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe the file format. You fiddling with JPG?

Comment: @AnderBiguri. Thank you very much and yes, I use .jpg for all the images. but how does this affect the graylevel values and how can I solve the problem?

Comment: jpg compresses the image, it doesnt save pixel information, but FFT coefficients, so there is always loss of information. Use lossless image format, such as png

Comment: @AnderBiguri, thank you for you suggestion, I have tried to convert the original image to grayscale and .png format. Then I do the cropping and saved the cropped image as .png as well. But the problem still exists.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, does manually cropping change the data in the image?

Comment: Yes it does,  or it can.  When you use jpg, you can never be sure you'll get the same pixels

Answer (score 0):

#### The reason might be on the Paint software.

I use other tools to crop the grayscale image, I then get a grayscale image and the graylevels are the same as original image.

While I use Paint, I will always get a truecolor image. This shows Paint has done something to the image. If I convert the cropped image into grayscale, the graylevel will be different from the original.